# d3 event propagation of the brush

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 brush with custom handles in order to give a great look to my selection. The selection of data works fine, but something is wrong with brush move event propagation of the handle. This is the chart: [image]

As you can see the custom handle is made of a dark grey rectangle and 3 dots in the middle. The handle looks as follows in devtools:

[image]

The problem is as follows when I drag handle using bar(rect) it works fine, but once I try to drag starting from dots in the middle it doesn't work.

```
      _appendHandles() {
        const { brushHeight } = this._chart;
        const range = this._chart.x.range();

        this._chart.handles = this._chart.brushElement.selectAll('.handle--custom')
          .data([{type: 'w'}, {type: 'e'}])
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr("class", d => `handle--custom handle--custom--${d.type}` )
          .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(${range[i]}, 0)`)

        this._chart.handles.append('rect')
          .attr("width", 7)
          .attr("height", brushHeight)

        this._chart.handles.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'dots-group')
          .selectAll('dots')
          .data([0, 1, 2])
          .enter()
          .append('circle')
          .attr('class', 'dot')
          .attr('cx', 3.5)
          .attr('cy', (d, i) => 2 + brushHeight/3 + i * (brushHeight/6))
          .attr('r', 3)
      }
```

I've tried:
 1. to move dots outside of 'dots-group' and it didn't help.
 2. Change the elements to be display(not circle but rect)

The problem is in the empty selection of dots ".selectAll('dots')". Once I remove it and append only one dot it works fine and I can drag using dot as well.

I would not like to draw each dot separately.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: why do you need to bind the values 0,1,2 to the dots, just do a regular JS foreach on the list of numbers and append a dot to your `dots-group` `g`. Maybe also remove the `pointer-events` on the `dots-group`.

Comment: Thx, it worked. But still... Why is it happening?

Comment: you don't want the dots to respond to mouse events, but that they are handled by the next lower element.